# Tooltip bug on the undelete link

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, tooltips

There's a deleted answer on Programmers where the option to undelete has a number beside it:

> undelete (1)

When I mouse over the (1), the tooltip says

> 2 more vote(s) needed to undelete this question

I think it should say "this answer" (or "this post") instead. And while I'm at it, I think it should also say "restore" instead of "undelete" to be consistent with the "vote to restore this post" tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It now no longer says "this question" all the time...probably not for over a year now, enjoy!

Comment: Looks like Christmas came so early this year that it was actually last year! ;)